# how can i run a where Clause to stored Procedure without edit it in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

if i have a SQL SERVER 2008 Stored Procedure that return a table of result , is it possible to run a `WHERE` Clause to the result table  with out editing the stored procedure itself ?

Comment: Alternatively you might try [openrowset hack](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/11/26/select-columns-from-exec-procedure-name-is-this-possible.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly.

Redirect the output to a temp table. Select and filter from that

```
CREATE TABLE #foo (...)

INSERT #foo EXEC bar @p1

SELECT * FROM @foo WHERE ...
```

Comment: is there is any other way of doing this direct way

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a #temp table to insert the results from the stored procedure into and then selecting from that with the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a Table Valued Function, and combine this with the other answers here ... ie: Create a TVF which creates a connection-local temporary table, populates that table with the results of the Stored Procedure call and returns the results.  You can then do a `SELECT` from that TVF applying the desired `WHERE` clause.

Though, this could be very slow with large datasets!!

Answer (score 0):

Openrowset is an option which comes into my mind it works like this

```
SELECT  *
FROM    OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;','set fmtonly off      exec master.dbo.sp_who')
AS tbl
```

You can apply  where clause directly.